# How to make pop() method to return and delete the second element in the stack?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I wrote an implementation of a `Stack` using Linked Nodes, but I want to add a method next to `pop()` that will remove the second item of the `Linkedstack` not the top item. I know that the point of implementing a stack is to only be able to remove the top item, but I need to implement this method.

This is the code for the `pop()` method I already have:

```
public T pop() {
    T top = peek();
    if (topNode != null)
        topNode = topNode.getNextNode();
    return top;
}
```

So what I want to do is let a new `node` point to the second element in the chain so I can return its value and then make `topNode` point to the first node as it is and then have that first node pointing to the third node in the chain so the second is deleted.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do two regular pop operations to remove the first two elements, and then push the first element back to the top of the stack and return the second element that was popped.